# Umbraco 7 tinyMCE RTE removing HTML5 tags

Tags: tinymce, umbraco7, rte

I installed Umbraco 7.2.5 and having issues with tinyMCE editor.
The richTextEditor is removing HTML5 tags, like `<section>`.

I have followed the instruction to edit tinyMceConfig.config file and allow any HTML by editing the following

```
<validElements><![CDATA[*[*]]]></validElements>
```

But this is not working.

I have restarted website in IIS, but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

PS.
I have another website running under Umbraco 6, and the above solution works.

Answer (score 4):

This is is likely due to TidyHtml and is an unfortunate issue indeed!

[Umbraco documentation shows /config/umbracosettings.config sections](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/config-files/umbracoSettings/)  where Tidy can be disabled.
Heads up that the `TidyEditorContent` element is no longer in the default instalation of this file but can easily be added back under the `content` section:

```
   <content>
        <TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent>
    <errors>
      <error404>1</error404>
```